# Is there any side-effect using *{transition: ease-in-out .2s all;}?

Tags: css

I try to add this line to my CSS segment:

```
.button {transition: ease-in-out .2s all;}
```

It would make the `.button` very pretty and smooth.

And later I tried this:

```
* {transition: ease-in-out .2s all;}
```

I find it makes every `:hover` element on my page look so pretty and smooth.

Is there any negative side-effect for doing this?

Comment: You are basically targeting all elements with all properties in the page. so everything will have transition effect, which is not good for consumer facing websites

Answer (score 3):

There are two sides of this.

1. It happens on all elements, and thus is kinda CPU heavy the larger the page, just to apply the rule to all elements.
2. You are using it for ALL attributes on all elements. Both width, height, transform — everything.

It might work well on new mobile phones, and desktop browsers, when you have a simple page. But the more you add to the page, the heavier this will get. And I think it will be very heavy on older mobile devices.

Comment: Cliff notes version: Generally a no-no if performance is any concern: 

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite catch the meaning of your comment.